# Redirecting to a different directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a full site setup at mysite.com/2/

I want urls like:

**mysite.com/about** to redirect to **mysite.com/2/about**

**mysite.com/work/photos** to redirect to **mysite.com/2/work/photos**

I was hoping I could solve this and add the /2 after the domain through the htaccess file and not have to move the whole site up a level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the folowing code if you want redirect

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(about|work/photos)/(2)
RewriteRule ^(about|work/photos)/(.*)$ /$1/2/$2 [R=301,L]
```

If you need only internal redirection change the last line with this :

```
RewriteRule ^(about|work/photos)/(.*)$ /$1/2/$2 [L]
```

If you want to change all requests :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(2)
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /$1/2/$2 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you friend. The change all requests worked for all the links in the site.

Comment: Actually, when i just go to www.mysite.com now it goes to www.mysite.com/222222222 and keeps refreshing.

Not sure if me updating my htaccess file a bunch today is messing with things

Comment: add this line to that code , put it under RewriteEngine On

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yourdomain\.com$

Comment: if you want to exclude www.mysite.com/  put this as well RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$

Comment: Thanks! Its giving me 404 errors and redirecting to the homepage. I do have this line for 404s in my htaccess: ErrorDocument 404     /2/index.php

Comment: So it seems its ignoring your rule and acting like mysite.com/about doesnt exist and redirecting to homepage.